# How to disable buttons until http request is processed/loaded in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-directive, scope

I want to write a directive that keeps a button and page disabled for the duration of the http request.

- If I update or submit a form, the button will disable until the http
  response is complete.
- When a page is loading, it will disable until the entire data is
  loaded from the server.
- After 10 seconds, the button will be active and the user can click
  multiple times.

**app.js**

```
<script>
var angModule = angular.module("myApp", []);

angModule.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.isSaving = undefined;
    $scope.btnVal = 'Yes';
    $scope.save = function()
    {
    $scope.isSaving = true;

    $timeout( function()
    {
        $scope.isSaving = false;

    }, 1000);
    };
});
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ng-form ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Saving: {{isSaving}}             

        <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="isSaving">
    <span ng-hide="isSaving">Save</span>
    <span ng-show="isSaving">Loading...</span><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="isSaving"></i>
      </button>


    </ng-form>
</div>
```

I am new to AngularJS, please help me write a directive for this.

Comment: You can find very useful information of how to create a custom directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a basic example :

```
<button ng-click="save()" loading="Loading..." notloading="save" disableonrequest>

myApp.directive("disableonrequest", function($http) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
      return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
    }, function(request) {
      if (!request) {
        element.html("<span >"+attrs.notloading+"</span>");
      } else {
        element.html("<span >"+attrs.loading+"</span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[A WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qnbasdkq/)

Comment: Thankyou Vanojx1 the problem is how it become a  reusable code it will applied only Button name as Save and while processing it will Loading..

Comment: Thank you Vanojx1 the problem is how it become a  reusable code, it will applied only button name as Save and while processing it will Loading..I want to use many places in the same.but button name is changed before and after request For example i need to my button name as Login and while processing it will changed to Processing.. instead of Loading..

Comment: Dear Vajonx one problem is here the button text shows undefined why?

Comment: First of all thank you for responding my comments.Actually i am using 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="updateProduct()" loading="Loading..." notloading="Update Product" disableonrequest></button>
But  it will shows up as undefined as button text it will not showing Update Product before processing and Loading while processsing.But any way working fine

Comment: sorry @SymonKt i ve used wrong parameter, now it will work fine, check the edit

Comment: Dear Vanojx one more  problem i faced the code is working fine firstly.,but it will not disabled while loading.Beacuse we will disable the button while request is processing, to avoid/preventing multiple submission .Thankyou

Comment: I added element.attr('disabled',true) but notloading button is disabled.how it will works help me thankyou

Comment: Please help me Vanojx I am facing one more problem in this code i need to disable that button untill that http proccesing is complete to avoid multiple clicking
 while processing have any way to modify that code.In this code  it will not disabled while loading.Beacuse we will disable the button while request is processing, 
to avoid/preventing multiple submission 

Actually I am adding element.attr('disable',true); But its not working It will disable on unloading time button

Comment: Add element.prop('disabled',true / false)   inside the if... ( don't use attr)

Comment: Ok Thankyou its working Vanojx.One more doubt man, I think I am irritating you.Sorry for that I am facing this issue thats why  I am asking again and again
Consider two buttons here Save and Cancel .When we click on that Save button how to disable both Save and Cancel buttons and vice -versa. Can you give me your mail id too.Ithink you are expert in this area Basically i am working in AngularJS just starting in a company after my PG .Please consider me If any inconvenience please I say sorry for you Give me your mail id too SymonKT

Comment: Im not here to code for you, i provided you a starting point for create what you need, then try to learn "how to" by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may not necessarily need a custom directive for this simple task.

You can simply set the `$scope.isSaving` property inside the callback for `$http`.

For example

```
$http({
        url: 'http://path/to/the/api/',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        }
    })
   .success(function(data, status){
        $scope.isSaving = false;
    })
   .error(....);
```